# iOS: UIBarButton Proper Size

Tags: ios, uitoolbar, uitoolbaritem

In my iOS application on UIToolbar I have added "Done" custom button with image.

```
UIBarButtonItem *btnNextDoneDisable;
UIToolbar *navigateQuestionBar;

//*to add button

UIImage *img_done = [UIImage imageNamed:DONE_RED_BTN_PNG(appDelegate.isIphone)];
        btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [btn setImage:img_done forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        btn.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, img_done.size.width, img_done.size.height);
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(doneClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        btnNextDoneDisable = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btn];

 [arrButtons addObject:btnNextDoneDisable];

navigateQuestionBar.items = arrButtons;
```

Done button image sizes are:

```
80 × 30

156 × 57
```

But this looks disturb on iPad Pro(11.0), [image: Like This.]

What is the proper size for button?

Answer (score 1):

The proper size for Navigation Bar and Toolbar Icons, according to Human Interface Guidelines should be:

```
+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
|         Target sizes          |         Maximum sizes         |
+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| 72px × 72px (24pt × 24pt @3x) | 84px × 84px (28pt × 28pt @3x) |
| 48px × 48px (24pt × 24pt @2x) | 56px × 56px (28pt × 28pt @2x) |
+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
```

Here is a reference to Apple's Guidelines: https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/custom-icons/

Comment: nice reference but not an answer to the question specified

Answer (score 0):

UIBarButtonItems have a fixed sizes and ignore any other size.

Additionally items added to a UINavigationBar or UIToolbar are placed by apple.

---

=> you cant set frame size or frame origin of your UIBarButtonItem

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that in iOS 11 you must set the size of your UIBarButtonItem's `customView` by using constraints (so that the item is sized "from the inside out"). You are not doing that; your button has a *frame*, but that is not the correct way to size it. Give the button height and width *constraints* so that the runtime knows how to size the bar button item.